# Getting DOM elements after div updated from load php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I have an html file with a div that gets updated by a php file. The php file puts a single  book's title and  author into the div, that works.
I am trying to use getElementById to get the book's title getElementById('btitle') and author name getElementById('authr') when I click a button because I need to use that information. I am not getting the value of the btitle or authr ids.  If I assign the whole div to a variable I get all of the div but I want them separate and the getElementByID() is not working.
Any help is appreciated.

```
a.html
'<div id='books'> </div>

addbooks.php
echo <stitle id='btitle'>Foundation</stitle>
echo <author id='authr'>Asimov</author>
```

Comment: Please post your javascript as well so we can where the issue might be.  A fiddle would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your javascript just before the closing `</body>` tag. Otherwise, if your javascript is in the head, it is looking for an element that has yet to be rendered to the DOM.

I tested the following and it returns the elements as you would expect.

```
<?php 
  echo "<stitle id='btitle'>Foundation</stitle>";
  echo "<author id='authr'>Asimov</author>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var title = document.getElementById('btitle').textContent,
     author = document.getElementById('authr').textContent;
  alert(title + " by: " + author);
</script>
```